# Jquery, rotate from center

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble rotating an image. What I need is the ability to rotate the image to a specific point on the click of a user. The problem is that the div is rotating from the top left.

I have specified the origin with CSS like:

```
 -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
```

and I am using this to initiate it:

```
$('.rotate1').click(function() {
    $('#tri1').transition({ rotate: '-280deg' }, 5000, 'ease');
});
```

**FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zz5uz/1/**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have the id on the div, not the image. change it to:

```
<div class="triangle-down1">
    <img src="../../testppoints.png"  id="tri1">   
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zz5uz/2/

Comment: Worked a treat! I will accept the answer once it has been 12 mins as it wont let me.